# Recuperar ClassName usando .Css() do AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma página que exibe várias `divs` que ao serem clicadas recupera e exibe os atributos utilizados para criá-las: `float`, `border`, `width` e etc.

Gostaria de recuperar o `classname`, porém não estou conseguindo.

Uso o AngularJS 1.2.1.

HTML:

```
<h2>Clique nas DIV´s para exibir os atributos do CSS</h2>

<div id="box1">1</div>
<div id="box2">2</div>
<div id="box3">3</div>
<div id="box4">4</div>
<p class="clear"></p>
<p id="result">&nbsp;</p>
```

Script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
$("div").click(function () {
    var html = ["<strong>A DIV selecionada possui os seguintes atributos:</strong>"];

    var styleProps = $(this).css(["classname","float", "border",
        "width", "height", "color", "background-color"]);
    $.each(styleProps, function (prop, value) {
        html.push(prop + ": " + value);
    });

    $("#result").html(html.join("<br>"));
});
}//]]>  

</script>
```

[Exemplo funcionando Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jothaz/wgzqrbkm/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jota, `className` não é uma propriedade CSS, mas sim uma propriedade do DOM (javascript). Para acessar esta propriedade bia jQuery, basta usar a função `attr`. Conforme segue:

HTML:

```
<h2>Clique nas DIV´s para exibir os atributos do CSS</h2>

<div id="box1" class="cname">1</div>
<div id="box2">2</div>
<div id="box3">3</div>
<div id="box4">4</div>
<p class="clear"></p>
<p id="result">&nbsp;</p>
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
    $("div").click(function () {
        var html = ["<strong>A DIV selecionada possui os seguintes atributos:</strong>"];

        var styleProps = $.extend({ classname: $(this).attr('class') || '' }, 
            $(this).css(["float", "border", "width", "height", "color", "background-color"])
        );
        console.log(styleProps);
        $.each(styleProps, function (prop, value) {
            html.push(prop + ": " + value);
        });

        $("#result").html(html.join("<br>"));
    });

    alert($("div").css('classname'));
})
```

[Exemplo funcionando Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jothaz/wgzqrbkm/14/)

Comment: Valeu funcionou corretamente, muito obrigado. https://jsfiddle.net/jothaz/wgzqrbkm/14/